# Votes count overflowing box for questions with more than 1000 votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, homepage

Once a question has received more than 999 votes and it appears in [the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/), aka the home page, the number of votes doesn't seem to fit into the square.

The [Hidden Features of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) has now received 1048 when I wrote this.

I am using Firefox 3.5.7 (so it shouldn't be some fringe case)

[image]

Comment: The elements `('div.votes div.mini-counts')` of those pages can only hold up to 3 digits, anything more will be cropped at the right edge. i.e. `999` fits, `1111` don't.

Comment: I noticed it on the same topic, was gonna report it but it's already done. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This now follows the same rules as views, and will be deployed later today.

Answer (score 11):

All we need is 49 people to downvote that question

Comment: And then we'd have another status-completed

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't edit post so here's the screenshot taken from Chrome, numbers are hacked in of course:

[image: Vote Overflow]

Should it be showing 1K or 1.1K instead?

Comment: According to the style established with kviews, it probably ought to be kvotes and a style change.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing the same here on both Safari and Firefox.

An alternative to displaying "1.1k" would be changing font-size.

Not good:

[image]

Better:

[image]

(150% for the font size size)

Comment: I apologize for the lack of freehand circles

Comment: Please add them if you want to avoid a flood of downvotes. Hurry!

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
.mini-counts {
    margin-left: -4px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}
```

Report back when it overflows 9999, then I'll think about it once again.