# Why isn't 1K votes instead of 1118 votes for Hidden features of C# ques?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, highest-voted-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Votes count overflowing box for questions with more than 1000 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39863/votes-count-overflowing-box-for-questions-with-more-than-1000-votes)

Why isn't 1K votes instead of 1118 votes for [Hidden features of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)?

Comment: Related post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39863/

Comment: Well, it is less than 2^10, right? Or were you thinking of 10^3?

Comment: @dmckee: I expected it to change after 512, aren't votes two bytes wide?  Maybe he should declare his encoding, just to keep things clear.

Comment: @dmckee: 1118 < 2^10? for shame!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's an edge case that is probably not worth fixing (yet - if ever).

Second, in the long discussions regarding the views (12.4 kviews vs 12k views) Jeff indicated that precision was important, and thus they weren't planning on postfixing numbers with k, m, etc.  Although you can see that they do with some question views (such as the highest voted questions)

Third, precision is *very* important on the page itself - when people vote, they want to see the number increment.  It will be very dissatisfying to vote up, and see `1.12k` change to `1.12k`.

I expect that 4 digits (up to 9999) will be sufficient for quite some time, and since it's an uncommon edge case anyway, a fix is unlikely.